# Mysql Cannot add foreign key constraint for my tables

Tags: mysql

Hey guys getting an Error code 1215, SQL state HY000: Cannot add foreign key constraint for my `PERSON_GROUP` table and `IMAGES` table.. Don't know why, is there something wrong with my referencing? I've tried rewriting it but its just not working...

Updated code im now just getting an error for `FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES INSTRUMENT(ID)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only create foreign keys that reference either the primary key or a unique key.  Since ID is the primary key of PERSON change your foreign keys to point to ID instead of email.  You could also make email a unique column, which is probably a good idea to make sure no one reuse the same email address, but it is still less storage to make foreign keys on an integer then a string.

Comment: So would adding `UNIQUE (email)` on the tables fix it?

Comment: @Vulcronos Be careful with the data types of the columns, e.g.:
`GROUPS: GID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`/`PERSON_GROUP: GROUPS_ID INT NOT NULL`
`INSTRUMENT: INSTRUMENTID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`/`IMAGES: INSTRUMENTID SMALLINT NOT NULL`

Comment: @Vulcronos I managed to solve most of them except the `FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES INSTRUMENT(ID)` @wchiquitop thanks for the code, I can see where I went wrong.

Comment: @Hayde You can't create a foreign key to a table you haven't created yet.  Move the create table statement for INSTRUMENT above the one for IMAGES.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The problem was database engine. Until i added the `ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1` before it worked. I guess my default was `innoDB` or something else.

```
CREATE TABLE LECTURE_NOTE (
  ID bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  NOTE VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, 
  NOTE_DATE TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  LECTURE_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PUBLISHER_ID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_lecture_id FOREIGN KEY (LECTURE_ID) REFERENCES 
  COURSE_LECTURE (ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_publisher_id FOREIGN KEY (PUBLISHER_ID) REFERENCES 
  PUBLISHER (ID)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```